# More intelligent touch events in angular-material

Tags: javascript, angularjs, touch, angular-material

**PREMISE**

[ngTouch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngTouch) is a library that makes touch events via ngClick more intuitive/close in behaviour to the standard touch model. Tap is a click; touch and hold can be handled in a unique way or fire the click event when the touch is released; releasing the touch when off of the original target does not fire the click event of the origin element. Angular Material, which my app uses, is not compatible with ngTouch.

**PROBLEM**

We've watched some users interact with the app on mobile and there are a lot of places where the click event of an element is being fired prematurely. For example: the user is trying to scroll through an image gallery and the detailed preview keeps popping up, so they can't scroll down. I believe that the actual click event is being tied to ontouchstart to eliminate the standard 300ms delay on clicks in vanilla angular, which means that any additional effects of the touch (i.e. holding, swiping) that differentiate it from a standard tap will be effectively ignored.

I'm looking for a means of mimicking the ngTouch intelligent touch events to prevent this sort of unintended behaviour. I don't think I can use a decorator, since that would involve me either overriding the ngClick directive with a completely new one (which I did before, but caused some serious problems with event delegation for a number of material elements) or accepting that fact that the normal click event will fire before my code and trying to deal with that retroactively. What are my options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to have been solved in the angular-material library natively as of 1.1.4.